# Does anyone know why the Custom Ajax Table in bootstrap is not working?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

The website is located here. It shows an example of the table but just keeps saying it's loading. Does ajax not work anymore with bootstrap tables?

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/table-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out. 
You have to add the ajax min.js. For some reason they don't show you in their example. So dumb.